# (placeholder) A userscript to show the reputation of users on the "Filtered Questions" stackoverflow page

Tags: script, placeholder

On the 'Filtered Questions' page of Stackexchange, I see a list of questions for the tags that I am interested in (or for a specific filter created by me). This list of questions shows the name of the users who have posted the questions. I wish to add the user reputation alongside the username.